# Should "Messages App" be specified as a device requirement in the info.plist if my app relies on MFMessageComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, info.plist, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

If `MFMessageComposeViewController` calls the Messages App (as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller), then I would expect `Messages App` would need to be specified under the `Required device capabilities` key in the info.plist file?

On iPhone, specifying `Messages App` as a required capability isn't an issue. However on iPad, specifying `Messages App` as a required capability causes conflict resulting in the following error:

```
Unable to install “MessageTest”
Domain: com.apple.platform.iphoneos
Code: -1
Recovery Suggestion: “MessageTest” requires the “sms” capability which is not supported by Jon's iPad
```

... even though this should be fine on an iPad as it can send iMessages via the Messages App. **NOTE:** `SMS` used to be a separate value under the `Required device capabilities` key, but is no longer there.

I have removed `Messages App` from the `Required device capabilities` key in the info.plist and the app installs on iPad, the `MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText()` method returns true, and an iMessage can be sent.  However, messaging is a critical capability of the app, so I don't want folks installing it and being disappointed (if for some reason messaging is not available on their device).

The following stack overflow posts don't answer the question.

[MFMessageComposeViewController doesn't send out the message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24818223/mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller-doesnt-send-out-the-message)

[Should I require sms capabilities in the info-plist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286907/should-i-require-sms-capabilities-in-the-info-plist)

The app is rather useless without messaging capability (if any user installs it and can't send a message then they **will** complain) but I don't see why I should exclude iPad users.

Should the `Required device capabilities` key in the info.plist specify `Messages App` or not?